# How to rename a lot of gibberish image names at once?

Tags: html, image, converters, jpeg

I recently downloaded plenty(33000) pictures from a server, which hosts a website that I run. Many of the pictures have gibberish naming, such as "Ч‘ЧђЧ ЧЁ-280x150.jpg".

These names were generally suppose to be in Hebrew but when I downloaded them from the server, their names became gibberish. I could of course just go over all the images and rename them using some gibberish translator, but I can't because there are thousands of images.

So I'm looking for a way to convert all the images with bad naming to images in Hebrew.

Comment: This seems impossible to solve with so little information.

Comment: _These names were generally suppose to be in Hebrew but when i downloaded them from the server, their names became gibberish._ How did that happen? Maybe your computer does not have the character sets to show Hebrew characters.

Comment: I am downvoting, as you received a high-quality answer without responding to it. Please be a part of this community, rather than just asking questions of it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my `gibberish-to-Hebrew` translator with me, but this will give your images a number instead of a name...

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
for f in *.jpg
do
   newname=$(printf "%06d" $i)
   echo mv "$f" "${newname}.jpg"
   ((i++))
done
```

Sample output:

```
mv 1500x1000.jpg 000001.jpg
mv 3000x2000.jpg 000002.jpg
mv a.jpg 000003.jpg
mv green.jpg 000004.jpg
mv new.jpg 000005.jpg
mv red.jpg 000006.jpg
```

Remove the word `echo` if you like the results.